# searchbar changes color when in navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I added a search bar in the titleview of a navigationitem. Searching works properly, but when using the navigation controller, the background of the searchbar changes colors, as seen below

The only place that I touch color is to change the color of the navigation item in the storyboard via xcode

the relevant code for putting the searchbar in the titleview

```
_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
[_searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.navigationItem.titleView = _searchController.searchBar;
```

What is causing this coloration?

[image]

trying to change the bartint color with

```
[_searchController.searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

but I am getting this [image]

also things that aren't working are

```
[_searchController.searchBar setBarTintColor:self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor];
_searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
```

and with `backgroundColor`

it seems that this color is somehow other than the settings. See here with redColor

[image]

Comment: I tried clearColor, doesn't work

Comment: How to make gif image like you uploaded problems image?

Comment: I use LICEcap for os x

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Need to set `UISearchBar` `tint color`.

```
UISearchBar *search=[[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 20)];
[search setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
search.backgroundImage=[UIImage new];
self.navigationItem.titleView=search;
```

Now navigation bar looks like below image :

[image]

Comment: unfortunatly, it doesn't work.. I added the gif for how it behaves with the code in the edit

Comment: `search.backgroundImage=[UIImage new];` fixed it for me; no need to set the `barTintColor` property.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift Users , just add these two lines :-

```
searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```